# Parallel execution of spark job using job-server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I'm using spark cluster in standalone mode + spark job-server for my written in Scala jobs execution. I launched job-server in docker container:

```
docker run -d -p 8090:8090 -e SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-server:7077 velvia/spark-jobserver:0.6.2.mesos-0.28.1.spark-1.6.1
```

I have test job jar with next code:

```
object Server extends SparkJob{


    override def runJob(sc: SparkContext, jobConfig: Config): Any = {
        sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3)).sum
    }

    override def validate(sc: SparkContext, config: Config): SparkJobValidation = SparkJobValid
}
```

I can successfully execute this job and get result using job-server. But when I'm trying to execute it in parallel some of them fail with next stack trace on job-server:

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.writeObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task$.serializeWithDependencies(Task.scala:200)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.resourceOffer(TaskSetManager.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$3$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:317)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$3$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$3.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:315)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$3.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:315)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint.org$apache$spark$scheduler$cluster$CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$makeOffers(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:196)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
        ... 39 more [2016-06-13 14:06:04,029] INFO  cheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/8b55da4a-sparkscala.Server]
- Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool [2016-06-13 14:06:04,030] ERROR cheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/8b55da4a-sparkscala.Server]
- Resource offer failed, task set TaskSet_0 was not serializable [2016-06-13 14:06:04,031] INFO  cheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/8b55da4a-sparkscala.Server]
- Cancelling stage 0 [2016-06-13 14:06:04,033] ERROR .jobserver.JobManagerActor [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/8b55da4a-sparkscala.Server]
- Got Throwable org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Failed to serialize task 0, not attempting to retry it. Exception during serialization: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1952)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(RDD.scala:1088)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1082)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sum$1.apply$mcD$sp(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sum$1.apply(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sum$1.apply(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions.sum(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:33)
        at sparkscala.Server$.runJob(Server.scala:15)
        at sparkscala.Server$.runJob(Server.scala:11)
        at spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:301)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [2016-06-13 14:06:04,037] ERROR .jobserver.JobManagerActor [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/8b55da4a-sparkscala.Server]
- Exception from job e195bde3-f17c-4add-bb7d-66e6a36ee48f: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Failed to serialize task 0, not attempting to retry it. Exception during serialization: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1952)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(RDD.scala:1088)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1082)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sum$1.apply$mcD$sp(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sum$1.apply(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sum$1.apply(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions.sum(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:33)
        at sparkscala.Server$.runJob(Server.scala:15)
        at sparkscala.Server$.runJob(Server.scala:11)
        at spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:301)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I run my job for parallel execution using job-server?

P.S. spark v 1.6.1
     spark job-server v. 0.6.2.mesos-0.28.1.spark-1.6.1
     scala 2.10

Comment: Did you try spark's FAIR scheduler?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Same result.